# Google Maps v2- Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager() on non-Activity class

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying create `non-Activity` class to show `my current location, get latitude/longitude, show markers`....on `Google Maps V2`but always its reports an error:

**Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()**

I tried:

**Part of My code**

```
public final class AddDataGMapsV2 {

    private static Context context;

    public AddDataGMapsV2(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void showMap(SupportMapFragment map, GoogleMap googleMap) {


        //show map
        //Line error below
        map = (SupportMapFragment) context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = map.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
    //.......................
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I find the solution to my question, only deleting that line:

```
 map = (SupportMapFragment) context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

And later declare on my principal activity...Simple.

Answer (score 0):

The Context doesn't have the getSupportFragmentManager(). You need to use the Activity class:

```
map = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: it solved only deleting that line, thanks to answer but it solved.